# NameError: name 'azureml' is not defined

Tags: python, r, azure, jupyter-notebook, reticulate

I have to run both python and R code in azure ml notebook but since [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73756887/attributeerror-module-pandas-has-no-attribute-float64dtype) is not working for me. So, I have made a `import_dataframe.py` file as:

```
import pandas
import subprocess
import sys

def read_df():
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", azureml-core])
    from azureml.core import Dataset, Datastore
    from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset

    subscription_id = 'abc'
    resource_group = 'pqr'
    workspace_name = 'xyz'

    workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)
    datastore = Datastore.get(workspace, 'workspaceblobstore')
    # create tabular dataset from all parquet files in the directory
    tabular_dataset_3 = Dataset.Tabular.from_parquet_files(path=(datastore,'/UI/09-17-2022_125003_UTC/userdata1.parquet'))
    df=tabular_dataset_3.to_pandas_dataframe()
    return df
```

Now in the notebook with `R` kernel, I am using the following lines of code:

```
library(reticulate)
source_python("import_dataframe.py")
df <- read_df()
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords): NameError: name 'azureml' is not defined

Traceback:

1. read_df()
2. py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords)
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this error ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did azureml get install successfully?

Comment: yes, when I run "import azureml" with python kernel, it runs successfully.

Comment: Is {reticulate} using the correct Python? Try `reticulate::py_config()` to see where {reticulate} is calling Python from. If the path doesn't match your expected Python installation, then it doesn't have access to the Python library. You can specify the appropriate installation using: `reticulate::use_python("path/to/your/Python")`

Comment: @AlexanderChristensen reticulate::py_config() says "python versions found" and shows the path for python3. I don't know why it is showing problem with only "azureml" library, when I use "pandas", it is working fine.