# Running R in jupyter notebook (epitools)

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I have successfully ran R code in jupyter notebook, but with a recent update to R (current version 4.2.3) some of the functionality is lost. The library I am calling is installed in R and works fine, but in Python it can't find the functions within the library (the library is found fine - initially I forgot to install the library after update, and the error I got was different).
[image]

Gives me an error:

```
R[write to console]: Error in oddsratio.wald(d) : could not find function "oddsratio.wald"


Error in oddsratio.wald(d) : could not find function "oddsratio.wald"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.py in eval(self, code)
    267                 # Need the newline in case the last line in code is a comment.
--> 268                 value, visible = ro.r("withVisible({%s\n})" % code)
    269             except (ri.embedded.RRuntimeError, ValueError) as exception:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py in __call__(self, string)
    437         p = rinterface.parse(string)
--> 438         res = self.eval(p)
    439         return conversion.rpy2py(res)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    198         return (super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self)
--> 199                 .__call__(*args, **kwargs))
    200 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    124                 new_kwargs[k] = conversion.py2rpy(v)
--> 125         res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
    126         res = conversion.rpy2py(res)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/conversion.py in _(*args, **kwargs)
     44     def _(*args, **kwargs):
---> 45         cdata = function(*args, **kwargs)
     46         # TODO: test cdata is of the expected CType

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    679             if error_occured[0]:
--> 680                 raise embedded.RRuntimeError(_rinterface._geterrmessage())
    681         return res

RRuntimeError: Error in oddsratio.wald(d) : could not find function "oddsratio.wald"


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RInterpreterError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-317691f663f1> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('R', '-i d ', 'w = oddsratio.wald(d)\n')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2360             with self.builtin_trap:
   2361                 args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
-> 2362                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2363             return result
   2364 

</Users/jilska2/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-130> in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.py in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)
    781             if not e.stdout.endswith(e.err):
    782                 print(e.err)
--> 783             raise e
    784         finally:
    785             if self.device in ['png', 'svg']:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.py in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)
    761                     return_output = False
    762             else:
--> 763                 text_result, result, visible = self.eval(code)
    764                 text_output += text_result
    765                 if visible:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.py in eval(self, code)
    271                 warning_or_other_msg = self.flush()
    272                 raise RInterpreterError(code, str(exception),
--> 273                                         warning_or_other_msg)
    274             text_output = self.flush()
    275             return text_output, value, visible[0]

RInterpreterError: Failed to parse and evaluate line 'w = oddsratio.wald(d)\n'.
R error message: 'Error in oddsratio.wald(d) : could not find function "oddsratio.wald"'
```

The same task in Rstudio

[image]

Any idea on how I can fix this? I have tried reinstalling rpy2 but got that all requirements are already satisfied.

Comment: An update - this is definitely related to version incompatibilities. I have now updated Python - got a pandas error as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73756887/attributeerror-module-pandas-has-no-attribute-float64dtype

I have updated pandas and now I'm getting a new error:
NotImplementedError: 
    Conversion rules for `rpy2.robjects` appear to be missing. Those
    rules are in a Python contextvars.ContextVar. This could be caused
    by multithreading code not passing context to the thread.